# How to fix '503 Service not found' for a specific REST api call?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, vue.js, heroku

I have a vue.js+Node.js+MongoDB app hosting at heroku and up until recently it worked fine.
Now, suddenly when im trying to do an action on the app that sends an 'add' POST to the server im getting this error : 
'POST http://www.mysportapp.co/user/add 503 (Service Unavailable)'

NOTES :

1. i didnt change nothing in the code, and it worked before.
2. when i first load my app there is an initial call to ther server that works.
3. when im running my app localy, it works fine, no errors.

```
//frontend function : 

async function saveUser(email) {
    var user = { email,date: Date.now()}
    var res = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/add`,user)
    localStorage.setItem('currUser',res.data)
    return res.data
}

//backend router : 

app.post(`${BASE}/add`, (req, res) => {
        const user = req.body
        userService.checkUser(user)
        .then(userDetails =>{
            brokerService.getDetails(userDetails)
            .then(brokerDetails => {
                req.session.brokerDetails = brokerDetails
                if (userDetails.isNew) sendGridService.createMsg(userDetails.email,userDetails.countryCode,brokerDetails)
                res.json(userDetails)
            })
        })
    })
```

Anyone has an idea what can be the reason for this ?

Comment: I had similar experience in past. for some reason one of my API was throwing exception and server starts to show 503 for future request until i restart my application. I would suggest, add the logs in suspicious code and handle the exception. This comment is based on my past experience.

Comment: For some reason it is now fixed after i added some logs and just deployed to heroku, thanks.

Comment: That is nice, When you deploy it restarts your APP. Keep an eye on logs you might find the issue.